# How to get a floating-point color from GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am currently faced with a problem closely related to the OpenGL pipeline, and the use of shaders.

Indeed, I work on a project whose one of the steps consists of reading pixels from an image that we generate using OpenGL, with as much accuracy as possible : I mean that instead of reading integers, I would like to read float numbers. (So, instead of reading the value (134, 208, 108) for a pixel, I would like to obtain something like (134.180, 207.686, 108.413), for example.)

For this project, I used both vertex and fragment shaders to render my scene. I assume that the color computed and returned by the fragment shader, is a vector of 4 floats (one per RGBA component) belonging to the "continuous" [0, 1] internal. But, how can I get it in my C++ file ? Is there a way of doing it ?

I thought of calling the `glReadPixels()` function just after having rendered my scene in a buffer, by setting the format argument to `GL_RGBA`, and the data type of the pixel data to `GL_FLOAT`. But I have the feeling that the values associated to the pixels that we read, have already been casted to a integer in the meanwhile, because the float numbers that I finally get, correspond to the interval [0, 255] clamped to [0, 1], without any gain in precision. A closer look on the OpenGL spectifications strengthens this idea : I think  there is indeed a cast somewhere between rendering my scene, and calling`glReadPixels()`.

Do you have any idea about the way I can reach my objective ?

Comment: There is `glClampColor (...)`, which can be used to modify the default behavior for reading from color buffers. It is not particularly useful though in most cases, and what you really want above all is to draw into a floating-point color buffer.

Comment: Dear Anton, many thanks for your answer ! However, I am afraid this tip doesn't work. Either I set the `clamp` parameter to `GL_TRUE` or `GL_FALSE`, I get the same results, with only 256 possible values per channel. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: Are you rendering into the default framebuffer (i.e. the device's back buffer). If so, the colours are likely being stored 1 byte per channel. You need to make your own framebuffer (see `glGenFramebuffers`, `glBindFramebuffer` etc.) and bind a floating point texture to it (with `glFramebufferTexture2D`).

Comment: @GuyRT : you were right !! Using a bidimensionnal texture was the good way to have this stranglehold broken. Now it works. Many thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

The GL_RGBA format returned by the fragment shader stores pixels components in 8-bit integers. You should use a floating point format, such as GL_RGBA16F  or GL_RGBA32F, where 16 and 32 are the depths for each component.

Comment: Fragment shaders always output floating-point components. It is really only after blending that things are converted into an unsigned normalized (fixed-point) format like `GL_RGBA` for storage.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but there is no `GL_RGBA16F` accepted paramater for `glReadPixels`, only `GL_STENCIL_INDEX`, `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` and `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL` apart from `GL_RGBA` and others. But the three first ones don't have anything to do with the last one, do they ?

Comment: They're not supposed to be passed to glReadPixels. Follow GuyRT comment. The "floating point texture" he mentions is just a texture generated with one of the floating point formats in my answer.

Comment: You and GuyRT were right about the texture and the `GL_RGBA32F` format. Now it works. Thanks a lot !!